# Deploy angular app on subpath (context) instead of root using express

Tags: angular, deployment, server, nodejs-server

Suppose i have one angular webapp on root ([www.demodomain.com](http://www.demodomain.com)), now i want to deploy another angular webapp on it's context path, ([www.demodomain.com/secondappp](http://www.demodomain.com/secondappp)), i am able load index.html but it's not loading main.js, polyfills.js etc,
here is my server.js,

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('http');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/secondappp/'));

app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/dist/secondappp/index.html')
});

const server = https.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log('worked'));
```

here is my index.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/secondapp/">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
  <p>TESTING ANGULAR IN NODE JS</p>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried changing the <base href="/secondapp/"> to  <base href="./"> in index,html

Comment: @Sreemat I have fixed it just couple of minutes ago, (used app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/'));)
Thanks for quick response though, much appreciated !